# How do I look at what's cached by Docker

Tags: docker

Experimenting and debugging a Dockerfile I change a line here and re-run and from the log output I can see "---> Using cache" and "---> b0efa....". My question is, where are those stored, am I filling my disk with detritus from my experimentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are ordinary images (more specifically layers).  You can look at what's inside by launching a container from one

```
docker run --rm -it b0efa sh
```

If you routinely run [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) that will clean up any unused images and the layers that go into them; if the cached layer is part of an image you're actually using, it takes no extra space.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, where are those stored...

The main storage is in layers, but the more visible part of docker's cache is in unnamed images. If you run the command:

```
$ docker image ls -a
REPOSITORY   TAG          IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
...
<none>       <none>       2ff3cc78bae3        2 months ago        990MB
<none>       <none>       b4d595b73712        2 months ago        990MB
<none>       <none>       a24136e532bd        2 months ago        990MB
...
```

you can see multiple `<none> <none>` lines. You can inspect those images to see what they are used for:

```
$ docker image inspect 2ff3cc78bae3
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:2ff3cc78bae335d793fbdfc3d4b2c802c790dceb99b870195d2ec24f3cb7c344",
        "Parent": "sha256:b4d595b7371298e378de8f5985dc63d5c1a44cf44b1a2b1d93b30f6e514cf72d",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Cmd": [       
                "/bin/sh", 
                "-c",      
                "#(nop) ", 
                "ARG IMAGE_PATCH_VER=0"
            ],
        ...
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:b28ef0b6fef80faa25436bec0a1375214d9a23a91e9b75975bba3b2889f8504f",
                "sha256:0b703c74a09c1e55d52e6b689babc6ae6374a793c1acfe8ff21a554014d8f434",
                "sha256:2eb1c9bfc5ead1e646e39ab760ead591f995cf606c327235a21eeb075ec5c178",
                "sha256:ab016c9ea8f8bb97f7b1c2871b0560787028864d06a49d062816ad72b9336cc6",
                "sha256:b7c56a9790e60bd54b54228e6b0d9c4328664b0692786b22e7de480e862770cc",
                "sha256:3b2a1688b8f31944a0ed33e09f5d241eb2c19da66b3a946866af8d30fcd17187",
                "sha256:3499b696191f1b2cf59ae755ca59d33b3de0c6f8f7671bdd71c30cd97c9335e8",
                "sha256:0d67aa2185d5678243a50613b5776c32c2f60022c15f593711d39f00f2d38285",
                "sha256:84bbcb8ef932ed7447fb7cdfb54952206a13b90f55a710ea2baad224b4be87dc",
                "sha256:156bc36c74a7ee16382e50c19370325c4d81b9d36ccd97c647b8e695e95b08ae",
                "sha256:9384f8c620b82317bf68d3e7ce67d30be265c53cb42ddee3894f00bd45f4957e",
                "sha256:ac25a83975980a489e2eb39128645895fbca444a4702fd0fe64ae72df52040ff",
                "sha256:61a39ec185581a88c0007f013ea155cd0aca0a4be61eb0cedc3f965dd9208f42",
                "sha256:40caba409f3cc8ce2dd84877730bfde9a74f8f057cebabd4887418c315adf24c",
                "sha256:b8e1d28b784040096a4fbb1c56820ff42975da14eb79093bf30bfba04b060ca9",
                "sha256:def95060ad1afb136328dbc9273098910a68878df6acda8f70a3f1100a6624e6",
                "sha256:0d21822b2d1e5c1873d31742109952f847f93623f404ec293d942ecdf6ad472e",
                "sha256:9288edafe57c1648cce14f1921080cc42901a8ffad88d3c2e2d08142c253d54c",
                "sha256:3b27b9cf51a6e6176966dc654aa47e6ef3ce19834224ed791cc23970db7d2fc5",
                "sha256:08794ff8753b0fbca869a7ece2dff463cdb7cffd5d7ce792ec067e3fd954fe01",
                "sha256:37986c5c5dff18257b9a12a19801828a80aea036992b34d35a33efdb743b2529",
                "sha256:34bb0412a3f6c0f3684e05fcd0a301dc999510511c3206d8cd34c538bfdb8b46",
                "sha256:c8a7927d0a54d0cac0aa417d61c936d3950d5f1514f4d080520a61205cd5ed4a",
                "sha256:cbb437280c0499a471745df063c647a646dfcc1745681466303df2c2af3efd92",
                "sha256:6599eb7e022c080e98cfd60e7570ebfda4be22917ea76b8d6bad16279a86c6b3",
                "sha256:f5fd05da7ca7dca9a48008b36a9a6ea2f330e426930dbe25f7b51e0eea2bccd2",
                "sha256:f5fd05da7ca7dca9a48008b36a9a6ea2f330e426930dbe25f7b51e0eea2bccd2"
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

The above output is significantly trimmed to show some key details.

First the parent points to the previous image in the build cache. Docker's cache depends on the previous step being the same from before. So if you add, or delete a line from the middle of a Dockerfile, this parent image will no longer match and you'll break the cache.

The next bit to note is the Cmd value, or command being run. In this case, it's a no-op comment from setting an ARG, but it could have been any command run from a RUN command. The environment and command being run need to be identical for the cache to match. With a COPY/ADD command, the checksum of the files being added need to match, which includes metadata like ownership and permissions on the file.

Lastly is the layers section, lets compare to the layers of the parent image:

```
$ docker image inspect b4d595b73712
[
    {
    ....
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:b28ef0b6fef80faa25436bec0a1375214d9a23a91e9b75975bba3b2889f8504f",
                "sha256:0b703c74a09c1e55d52e6b689babc6ae6374a793c1acfe8ff21a554014d8f434",
                "sha256:2eb1c9bfc5ead1e646e39ab760ead591f995cf606c327235a21eeb075ec5c178",
                "sha256:ab016c9ea8f8bb97f7b1c2871b0560787028864d06a49d062816ad72b9336cc6",
                "sha256:b7c56a9790e60bd54b54228e6b0d9c4328664b0692786b22e7de480e862770cc",
                "sha256:3b2a1688b8f31944a0ed33e09f5d241eb2c19da66b3a946866af8d30fcd17187",
                "sha256:3499b696191f1b2cf59ae755ca59d33b3de0c6f8f7671bdd71c30cd97c9335e8",
                "sha256:0d67aa2185d5678243a50613b5776c32c2f60022c15f593711d39f00f2d38285",
                "sha256:84bbcb8ef932ed7447fb7cdfb54952206a13b90f55a710ea2baad224b4be87dc",
                "sha256:156bc36c74a7ee16382e50c19370325c4d81b9d36ccd97c647b8e695e95b08ae",
                "sha256:9384f8c620b82317bf68d3e7ce67d30be265c53cb42ddee3894f00bd45f4957e",
                "sha256:ac25a83975980a489e2eb39128645895fbca444a4702fd0fe64ae72df52040ff",
                "sha256:61a39ec185581a88c0007f013ea155cd0aca0a4be61eb0cedc3f965dd9208f42",
                "sha256:40caba409f3cc8ce2dd84877730bfde9a74f8f057cebabd4887418c315adf24c",
                "sha256:b8e1d28b784040096a4fbb1c56820ff42975da14eb79093bf30bfba04b060ca9",
                "sha256:def95060ad1afb136328dbc9273098910a68878df6acda8f70a3f1100a6624e6",
                "sha256:0d21822b2d1e5c1873d31742109952f847f93623f404ec293d942ecdf6ad472e",
                "sha256:9288edafe57c1648cce14f1921080cc42901a8ffad88d3c2e2d08142c253d54c",
                "sha256:3b27b9cf51a6e6176966dc654aa47e6ef3ce19834224ed791cc23970db7d2fc5",
                "sha256:08794ff8753b0fbca869a7ece2dff463cdb7cffd5d7ce792ec067e3fd954fe01",
                "sha256:37986c5c5dff18257b9a12a19801828a80aea036992b34d35a33efdb743b2529",
                "sha256:34bb0412a3f6c0f3684e05fcd0a301dc999510511c3206d8cd34c538bfdb8b46",
                "sha256:c8a7927d0a54d0cac0aa417d61c936d3950d5f1514f4d080520a61205cd5ed4a",
                "sha256:cbb437280c0499a471745df063c647a646dfcc1745681466303df2c2af3efd92",
                "sha256:6599eb7e022c080e98cfd60e7570ebfda4be22917ea76b8d6bad16279a86c6b3",
                "sha256:f5fd05da7ca7dca9a48008b36a9a6ea2f330e426930dbe25f7b51e0eea2bccd2",
                "sha256:f5fd05da7ca7dca9a48008b36a9a6ea2f330e426930dbe25f7b51e0eea2bccd2"
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

If you look through those layers, which is where all the files are stored, you will see that they are identical. Adding an ARG to an image creates no new files, so this is expected. If it was a RUN or COPY command, you'd see all the same layers except for one additional layer in the new image. When you run a container, docker uses the pointers to these layers to create an overlay filesystem that accesses the layers as read-only slices of the filesystem (with the container having it's one read-write slice at the top). **The important part here is that these layers don't get copied, multiple images can point to the same layers.**

> am I filling my disk with detritus from my experimentation?

It depends. If your images are changing significantly, and you are using the same tag for each build, then you may have lots of orphaned (untagged) images taking up a large amount of disk space. A `docker image prune` will remove the orphaned images, and the parts of the build cache that are no longer used by any tagged images. If you maximize image caching by keeping your changes to only the last layers, and minimize the size of those changes, and use a unique tag per build, then you will see little benefit from an image prune and the cache is taking up hardly any space.

Comment: I have some cached layers during failed build but they don't show up in `docker image ls -a` output. How do I list those?

Comment: @timurb this answer was from before buildkit was enabled by default (I'm not even sure it was GA). The buildkit cache isn't visible like the classic builder cache was.